# Plotting predicted values in GLM in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, generalized-linear-model, contrasts

I am trying to find a more aesthetic way to present an interaction with a quadratic term in a logistic regression (categorisation of continuous variable is not appropriate).

For a simpler example I use a linear term.

```
set.seed(1)

df<-data.frame(y=factor(rbinom(50,1,0.5)),var1=rnorm(50),var2=factor(rbinom(50,1,0.5)))
mod<-glm(y ~ var2*var1  , family="binomial" , df)

 #plot of predicted probabilities of two levels

new.df<-with(df,data.frame(expand.grid(var1=seq(-2,3,by=0.01),var2=levels(var2))))
pred<-predict(mod,new.df,se.fit=T,type="r")

with(new.df,plot(var1,pred$fit))

 #plot the difference in predicted probabilities

trans.logit<-function(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))

pp<-trans.logit(coef(mod)[1] + seq(-2,3,by=0.01) * coef(mod)[3]) -trans.logit((coef(mod)[1]+coef(mod)[2]) + seq(-2,3,by=0.01) * (coef(mod)[3]+coef(mod)[4]))

plot(seq(-2,3,by=0.01),pp)
```

#### Questions

- How can I plot the predicted probability difference between the two levels of var2 (rather than the 2 levels separately)  at different values of var1?
- Is there a way to define contrasts so I can use these in the glm so I can then pass this to predict? - I need a CI for the difference in probabilities

Comment: Do you mean you need a CI for the difference of  the prediction?

Comment: yes, CI for the difference across range of var1.

Answer (score 3):

The `rms` package has a general `contrast.rms` function that also works with the `glht` function in the `multcomp` package to give simultaneous confidence intervals.  This works for log odds ratios (and hence odds ratios).  I will investigate whether it is easy to add an option to get bootstrap confidence intervals for differences in probabilities.  We generally use the odds ratio scale because odds ratios can be independent of the settings of other variables in the model.  Risk differences must be considered for a whole array of settings of the other covariates in the model.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll have a look at rms. I actually ended up bootstrapping the CI's at the time as i couldn't find another way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options:

You can use the `glht` function in the multcomp package for R and specify your own contrasts/comparisons.  The result can be used with the `confint` function to compute the confidence intervals.

You can use the `Predict.Plot` function in the TeachingDemos package for R (and the related `TkPredict` function) to create plots that will demonstrate how the predictions change with the variables.

You fit the model using Bayesian methods and MCMC, then you just do the calculation that you want to get the posterior distribution of the combination of interest and plot that, or the intervals based on them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions Greg. I am familiar with glht for testing effects of interactions but i have been unable to find a way to use it to generate predicted probabilities. Just had a quick look at your TeachingDemos package, ill see if tkpredict does whats needed. Thanks

Comment: @user20650, the `glht` function would not generate the predicted probabilities, but rather can compute confidence intervals on combinations of parameters, which it seems is what you were asking how to do. Think about the formula when var1 is 1 and when it is 0, then subtract, is that not what your original question asked for?  (though this would be a difference on the logit scale, not the probability scale).

Comment: Yes Greg sorry about the confusion. After reviewing my original question i realised i could of been clearer - added the word probability and plots to illustrate in the update. I would like to present on the probability scale as log odds is not as clinically interpretable. But thanks for your time.